# desktop byobu launcher doesn't read my ~/.byobu/windows.ssh_sessions file

Tags: gnome-terminal, byobu

Any idea why the desktop launcher "gnome-terminal -x byobu" doesn't read my ~/.byobu/windows.ssh_sessions?

Here's my ~/.byobu/windows.ssh_sessions file I use with byobu successfully:

```
screen -t Ubu-MySQL ssh master@192.168.1.3
screen -t Ubu-alfresco ssh master@192.168.1.4
screen -t Ubu-Master ssh master@192.168.1.5
screen -t Ubu-zimbra ssh master@192.168.1.6
screen -t Ubu-SugarCRM ssh master@192.168.1.7
screen -t Ubu-eFront ssh master@192.168.1.8
```

and here's the variable entry from my .bashrc:

```
export BYOBU_WINDOWS=/home/jj/.byobu/windows.ssh_sessions byobu
```

I tried it in .profile also, no love.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hrm.. Fixed. I ran byobu-launcher and setup some new windows. Then made a .sh script with byobu-launcher in it. chmod 700 (and a she-bang! of course)scr

Comment: "gnome-terminal -x /home/jj/bin/Ubu-Screens.sh" is the launcher property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you're supposed to start byobu by running `byobu-launcher`, which handles all the setup details and config files.

Edit: You are setting an environment variable in `.bashrc`, which means it will only be set in bash. Running byobu directly from gnome-terminal means that bash is not involved. Putting the environment variable in `.profile` should make it session-wide, but you would have to log out and back in for it to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for the clue, but neither "gnome-terminal -x byobu-launcher" or just "byobu-launcher" from the desktop icon is reading the windows.ssh_sessions file.  I even tried "gnome-terminal -x byobu-launcher -c ~/.byobu/windows.ssh_sessions". No love.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, +1 for the clue. Exact instructions are at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10228516#post10228516

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, with the answer nearly in your own question!

All you need is:

```
export BYOBU_WINDOWS=ssh_sessions byobu
```